# How to convert a netty ByteBuf to a String and vice versa

Tags: java, encoding, netty, decoding

Is there a way to convert a netty ByteBuf to a String and vice versa?

```
public String toString(ByteBuf b){

 //return b enconded to a String
}

public Bytebuf ToByteBuff(String s){

  //return s decoded to Bytebuf
}
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can use [`ByteBuf.toString(Charset)`](https://netty.io/4.1/api/io/netty/buffer/ByteBuf.html#toString(java.nio.charset.Charset)) to convert to string.

You can use [`String.getBytes(Charset)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getBytes(java.nio.charset.Charset)) and [`Unpooled.wrappedBuffer(byte[])`](https://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/buffer/Unpooled.html#wrappedBuffer(byte[])) to convert to ByteBuf.

Comment: This was very helpful even though it's so simple lol. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 4):

You can create a `ByteBuf` from a String with `Unpooled.copiedBuffer(String, Charset)`.

Answer (score 2):

To convert ByteBuf to String, it needs:

```
 public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) {
        ByteBuf in = (ByteBuf) msg;
        String clientMessage = in.toString(CharsetUtil.UTF_8);
```

To convert String to ByteBuf, it needs:

```
 String message = "text";
 ByteBuf in = Unpooled.wrappedBuffer(message.getBytes());
```