# Response has 2 bytes per character in Netty

Tags: java, http, encoding, character-encoding, netty

In Netty, I create a response by feeding a String in `body`:

```
        DefaultFullHttpResponse res = new DefaultFullHttpResponse(HTTP_1_1, httpResponse.getHttpResponseStatus());
        if (body != null) {
            ByteBuf buf = Unpooled.copiedBuffer(body, CharsetUtil.UTF_8);
            res.content().writeBytes(buf);
            buf.release();
            res.headers().set(HttpHeaderNames.CONTENT_LENGTH, res.content().readableBytes());
        }
```

When I look at the response, I see `content-length` being twice the length of the characters in the String. I understand the Java String contains 2 bytes per character, but I can't figure out how to prevent this in Netty when returning the request.

When I look at Cloudflare responses, these contain one byte per character. So there must be a way to change this. Ideas?

Comment: `res.content().clear(); res.content().writeBytes(buf);` Maybe somehow the content holds twice the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Chris O'Toole shows in [How to convert a netty ByteBuf to a String and vice versa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40289204/how-to-convert-a-netty-bytebuf-to-a-string-and-vice-versa) we must

- first convert the String to Byte Array using the desired charset (UTF-8 works fine) `String.getBytes(Charset)`,
- then `Unpooled.wrappedBuffer(byte[])` using the Byte Array instead the
  String.

One byte per character for most characters, as @rossum stated.

Answer (score -1):

Use US_ASCII charset instead of UTF-8. Haven't tested, try.

Comment: For most common characters UTF-8 only needs a single byte.  Two bytes per character is either a non-Latin alphabet or the original is in UTF-16, which is always two bytes per character, and the Java default IIRC.

Comment: @rossum `copiedBuffer` says this: "Creates a new big-endian buffer whose content is the specified {@code string} encoded in the specified {@code charset}. The new buffer's {@code readerIndex} and {@code writerIndex} are {@code 0} and the length of the encoded string respectively." If what you say and the specification are correct, UTF-8 should work just fine, even if the original Java String was UTF-16. What you say is how I believe UTF-8 should work. A bug in Netty 4.1.15 maybe?

Comment: @Oliver What charset have you specified in `{@code charset}`?

Comment: @rossum UTF-8, I expected the buffer to be copied from String to UTF-8. I found two things: https://netty.io/4.1/api/io/netty/util/AsciiString.html and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40289204/how-to-convert-a-netty-bytebuf-to-a-string-and-vice-versa - will try these tomorrow and post results.

Comment: As @Chris O'Toole shows in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40289204/how-to-convert-a-netty-bytebuf-to-a-string-and-vice-versa we must first convert the String to Byte Array using the desired charset (UTF-8 works fine) `String.getBytes(Charset)`, then `Unpooled.wrappedBuffer(byte[])` using the Byte Array instead the String. One byte per character for most characters, as @rossum stated.